# Can I run Chrome Beta side by side with regular Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I'd like to have both **Chrome stable and Beta running simultaneously** so I can test my site in both of them.

I do know that I can run [Chrome Canary](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/chrome-canary-for-developers/) side by side with another Chrome, but I don't want to do that right now.

When I try running Beta while Stable is running it just quits immediately.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yup, you can do this as long as you're okay keeping the profiles for your beta and stable separate.

These instructions below are for Mac, but you can probably work out the Windows equivalents.

- [Download the Beta](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/beta.html).
- Extract the app to Downloads
- Rename the beta app to `Google Chrome Beta.app` and move into *Applications* folder.
- Run this in terminal:

  - `/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=/Users/$USER/chromebetaprofile`
  - The path after **--user-data-dir=** is where your profile for Chrome Beta will live. Move it somewhere else if you like, but use an absolute path (`~` doesn't work here).
- You are now running Chrome Beta side by side with stable.
- Optional: If you'd like to avoid going to the command line, you can make an .app with the `user-data-dir` baked in with [appify](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps) or the [Appify-UI](https://github.com/subtleGradient/Appify-UI)

Now to get a nice icon to differentiate:

- Open https://github.com/alrra/browser-logos/blob/master/src/chrome-beta/chrome-beta.png
- Click the `Download` button
- Select the Beta app in Finder > Applications
- Hit <kbd>cmd-i</kbd> for the file details
- Click the icon in the top left, it should give you a blue focus highlight
- <kbd>cmd-v</kbd> to paste in the new icon.

Aw yeah. Canary, Beta, Stable in peace and harmony:

[image]

Comment: And I'm guessing there are no issues with the automagic updates for each of the versions...?

Comment: You can install/update Chrome and Chrome Canary with [Homebrew Cask](https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask) via the command line, but there's no Cask for Chrome Beta. You could write your own, of course.

Comment: @Lipis I expect it to autoupdate yes.

Comment: This works perfectly except that I don't have an icon in the system tray for chrome beta. Your command launches it successfully from the terminal but I feel like there's a couple steps missing to get that terminal command to launch from an icon in the tray.

Comment: Here is another way of automating the launch without the command line: https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory

Comment: Good instructions - PNG link throws 404 :(

Comment: updated the image

Comment: Does this also works if I want to have run two betas (or stable) side by side?

Comment: For the icon, you may need to open it in Preview and copy the contents to paste in the icon in file info. OS X 10.12.3

Comment: To start the Chrome Beta application, you can also create an Automator script to run command `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Beta.app --args --user-data-dir=/Users/<your_username>/chromebetaprofile`